# Apply a function on value multidimentionnal array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array with the hours of production like this (the number of array is not fixed, somethimes we can have production in January, not in february, and restart in March etc...) :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 8
            [HoursProd] => 181.37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 9
            [HoursProd] => 699.35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 10
            [HoursProd] => 500.25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 11
            [HoursProd] => 350.61
        )


)
```

I want to divide the hours in my array by the number of hours in the month. Get the month key (number of th month), calculate the number of hours in this month, and divide my Hours value by this number.

For the number of hours, i write this code for try to have the total of hours in a month.:

```
    $m = 1;
 $a = date('m');
 $y = date("y");
 $result2 = array();

 for($m; $m <= 12; $m++){
 $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$m,$y);

 $result2[]["HoursTotalMonth"] = $d * 24;
 $result2[]["Month"] = $m;
 $t = $d * 24;

//To simplify the problem, i try to convert Hours of the month in the same array of production, and wheen the value of month is the same, divise value hours prod by value of hours total month

 $test[] = array("Month" => $m, "HoursTotalMonth" => $t);

 };
```

I try lot of things whithout success. The goal being at the end to be able to create a Json file to create a chart with ChartJS, The goal being at the end to be able to create a Json file to create a graph with ChartJS, with the production hour / hour ratio of the month in percentage. I succeed with a simple array but not with an associative multidimentional array.

Ex : [Month] => 8
     [RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth] => 24.37 // (181.37 / (31j*24h))

I want this array :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 8
            [RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth] => 24.37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 9
            [RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth] => 97.13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 10
            [RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth] => 67.23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 11
            [RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth] => 48.69
        )

)
```

To be able to use the Json encoder, like this one:

```
[{"Month":8,"RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth":24.37},{"Month":9,"RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth":97.13},{"Month":10,"RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth":67.23},{"Month":11,"RatioHoursProdOnHoursTotalMonth":48.69}]
```

Comment: Can you provide the output you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you expect as output ?

```
$a = date('m');
$y = date("y");
$result = array();
$data = array(100,60,75,90,58,98,105,85,74,685,700,550);

for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++){
    $d = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $y);

    $result[] = [
        "Heure" => $d * 24,
        "Mois" => $m,
        "ratio" => $data[$m - 1] * 100 / ($d * 24),
    ];
};

print_r($result);
```

Comment: I have edit my post with more explanation and a example of the result i want. In your example of output, the var $data is just a test with a simple array (not dimmentional like the first array in my post). First , i have the idea to change the first array and replaces "Hours" by "ratio" but after reflexion, just add "Ratio" in my original array may be more simple and reliable. But i don't know how to make a foreach and condition for get the value of the month, convert it to a number of hours total and divise the hours value by number of hours total, to obtain the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Melvyn Marigny, the code below make the output i want.

```
$m = 1;
$a = date('m');
$y = date("y");

$nb = count($result);

for ($m = 1; $m <= $nb; $m++){
    $d = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $y);

        $result3[] = [
            "Mois" => $result[$m - 1]["Mois"],
            "HeureProd" => $result[$m - 1]["Heure"],
            "HeureMois" => $d * 24,
            "ratio" => $result[$m - 1]["Heure"] / ($d * 24),
    ];
    }

print_r($result3);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Mois] => 8
            [HeureProd] => 181.37
            [HeureMois] => 744
            [ratio] => 0.24377688172043
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Mois] => 9
            [HeureProd] => 753.39
            [HeureMois] => 696
            [ratio] => 1.0824568965517
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Mois] => 10
            [HeureProd] => 1292.25
            [HeureMois] => 744
            [ratio] => 1.7368951612903
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Mois] => 11
            [HeureProd] => 376.11
            [HeureMois] => 720
            [ratio] => 0.522375
        )
```